# In what cases would using a non-resonant spectroscopy be preferable to using the resonant type?

Tags: solid-state-physics, spectroscopy

[Here](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Physical_Chemistry/Spectroscopy/Vibrational_Spectroscopy/Raman_Spectroscopy/Resonant_vs._Nonresonant_Raman_Spectroscopy) it is mentioned that non-resonant Raman spectroscopy is desirable for avoiding fluorescence and for studying water due to water's low polarizability. How is non-resonant Raman desirable in the latter case? Are there any other reasons why non-resonant Raman (or any non-resonant) spectroscopy may be preferable to the resonant type?

Comment: Maybe, the author meant that in solvents with high polarizability the non-resonant Raman signal of solvent is very strong, so resonant Raman spectroscopy is required to get reasonable signal. And the low polarisability of water means low background signal that allows using non-resonant Raman spectroscopy to study dissolved samples. I'm just guessing as I have almost no experience of Raman spectroscopy in condensed phase.

Comment: Low polarizability would mean low signal, so wouldn't resonant Raman actually be preferred in that case since it enhances the signal?

Comment: Note: the page that you linked refers to studying "water-containing samples", not "water". It is good if the Raman signal of water itself is weak - then you can use non-resonant Raman on your sample, avoiding problems with fluorescence.